# Exception in Database

Tags: java, database

HI

I made a method in my class that is:

```
public void addInfo(String username, String password, String name, String family) {
        try {

 String sql = "INSERT INTO user VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            pst.setString(1, username);
            pst.setString(2, password);
            pst.setString(3, name);
            pst.setString(4, family);
            int nRecords = pst.executeUpdate();
            logger.info("User Added Successfully...");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.info("ERROR in adding user");

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And then I retrieve this in my addInfo class:

```
 private void AcceptButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

        String name = NameField.getText().trim();
        String family = FamilyField.getText().trim();
        String username_signup = UsernameSignUp.getText().trim();
        String password = new String(PasswordSignUp.getPassword()).trim();

        if ((name == null ? "" == null : name.equals("")) || (family == null ? "" == null : family.equals("")) || (username_signup == null ? "" == null : username_signup.equals("")) || (password == null ? "" == null : password.equals(""))) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fill the blanks...", "WARNING", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            clearAll();
            NameField.grabFocus();
            return;

        } else {

            UserManager um = new UserManager();
            um.addInfo(username_signup, password, name, family);

            FirstPage fp = new FirstPage();
            this.setVisible(false);
            fp.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

But I face with these exceptions:

```
run:
Jan 9, 2010 3:54:20 PM DBManager.UserManager addInfo
INFO: ERROR in adding user
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to retrieve metadata for procedure.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.extractProcedureName(CallableStatement.java:1076)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:1026)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:83)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:1204)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:1181)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conn.prepareCall(sql)` should only be used for invoking stored procedures, not raw SQL.

Replace your `prepareCall` with `prepareStatement`, and you should be fine.

Comment: You guys are bloody fast.  I was just done reading the code when there were two answers already.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [prepareStatement()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement%28java.lang.String%29). [prepareCall()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall%28java.lang.String%29) is used for calling stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `prepareCall`. It's only used for stored procedures. You should use [`prepareStatement`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just one more point: you aren't cleaning up resources at all.  You've got a PreparedStatement that's eligible for GC when you exit the block, but you don't close it anywhere.  Close it in a finally block using a static method that doesn't throw an exception:

```
public void insert(Connection connection)
{
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try
    {   
        // SQL stuff here.
    }
    finally
    {
        close(ps);
    }
}

public static void close(Statement s)
{
    try
    {  
        if (s != null)
        {
            s.close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Same holds true for Connection and ResultSet.

No transactional logic for you, either.  Usually you want to rollback write operations in the event of a failure.

Comment: +1 for the closing. Plus it's worth looking (perhaps) at Apache DbUtils.close/closeQuietly, which do the above for connections/statements/resultsets and are null aware